# Python: How to pass a list of iterables to zip when the list is only determined at runtime?

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

I would like to use zip to iterate in lock step over the elements of various generators. Which generators and how many of them there will be is only known at run time.
However, I can't work out how to pass this into zip as any list will be interpreted as an iterable rather than the list of iterables which must be simultaneously iterated over.

What's the correct way to do this?
Also, what's the correct way to unpack the outputs when their number isn't known until runtime?
Below is what I have tried

```
from typing import List

l_1 = [1, 2, 3]
l_10 = [10, 20, 30]
l_100 = [100, 200, 300]

def gen(l_: List):
    for i in l_:
        yield i

# Standard: works fine as expected
for i, j, k in zip(gen(l_1), gen(l_10), gen(l_100)):
    print('i={}, j={} k={}'.format(i,j,k))

# List of generators prepared at run time. Does not work
gens = [gen(l_1), gen(l_100)]
receive = [None] * len(gens)
for receive in zip(gens):
    print(receive)
```

The output is

```
i=1, j=10 k=100
i=2, j=20 k=200
i=3, j=30 k=300
(<generator object gen at 0x000001C3DB93C258>,)
(<generator object gen at 0x000001C3DB93C620>,)
```

The desired output is

```
i=1, j=10 k=100
i=2, j=20 k=200
i=3, j=30 k=300
[1, 100]
[2, 200]
[3, 300]
```

How can I get zip to recognize that gens is not an iterable to iterate over, but rather the list of iterables which must be iterated over in lock step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be only a small change, to pass a list of iterables to zip you have to unpack it using `*`

```py
# List of generators prepared at run time. Does not work
gens = [gen(l_1), gen(l_100)]
receive = [None] * len(gens)
for receive in zip(*gens):
    print(list(receive))
```

edit:
since you expected lists in your output I had to explicitly convert receive to a list.

Comment: Nice. Thanks so much. What do you think about the receive bit? Is that a reasonable way to do it? Other ways?

Comment: I hadn't really looked at that! I don't know what 'receive' stands for. When you use `receive = [None] * len(gens)`, is that meant to be a backup for when the loop doesn't run properly? Because by naming your loop-variable `receive` as well, you overwrite the list of `None`s

Comment: Also keep in mind that the `receive` variable in the loop will be an immutable list of type `tuple`, if you ever need to manipulate it, you should convert it to something mutable. (`receive = list(receive)` would be a nifty hack I guess)

Comment: Yeah, the `receive = [None] * len(gens)` serves no purpose. Can be safely removed. I was head in the clouds mechanically declaring a variable with the correct dimensions to receive the zip result. Clearly that doesn't happen, nor is it needed. I'm not thinking in Python yet...

Comment: I can't imagine what it would be like learn python when you're already used to these lower level steps. I have issues with understanding differences between initialisation/declaring/defining variables. Pythonic thinking can be limiting, I guess, but it allows us to think more about the whole algorithm (at the cost of performance, I must say)